# SQLite x Python insert table returns "False", no idea why

Tags: python, sqlite, sql-insert

I try to make a simple contact book in Python in cooperation with SQL database, and when I try to make a query, my INSERT function returns false.

Here's my declaration of tables

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMessageBox
from PyQt5.QtSql import QSqlDatabase, QSqlQuery


def _createContactsTable():
    """Create the contacts table in the database."""
    createTableQuery = QSqlQuery()
    return createTableQuery.exec(
        """
        CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS contacts (
            id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCRE MENT UNIQUE NOT NULL,
            short VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
            fullname VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
            postcode VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
            city VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
            street VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
            phone VARCHAR(50),
            email VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL
        )
        """
    )


def createConnection(databaseName):
    """Create and open a database connection."""
    connection = QSqlDatabase.addDatabase("QSQLITE")
    connection.setDatabaseName(databaseName)

    if not connection.open():
        QMessageBox.warning(
            None,
            "CustomersManager",
            f"Błąd bazy danych: {connection.lastError().text()}",
        )
        return False

    _createContactsTable()
    return True
```

And, there's a query

```
from struktura.database import createConnection

# Create a connection
createConnection("contacts.sqlite")


# Confirm that contacts table exists
from PyQt5.QtSql import QSqlDatabase
db = QSqlDatabase.database()
db.tables()

from PyQt5.QtSql import QSqlQuery

insertDataQuery = QSqlQuery()
insertDataQuery.prepare(
    """
    INSERT INTO contacts (
        short,
        fullname,
        postcode,
        city,
        street,
        phone,
        email
    )
    VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
    """
)
```

This procedure is creating a new sqlite file, but it's empty. Can't fill it with table propeties. When I made simple one with three values in table, it worked. Where is the problem?

Comment: Have you tried defining the schema first and then writing to it?

Comment: Looking at [this](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsqlquery.html#prepare) example, your code isnt `prepare`ing the query right. How are you binding the values? When does the code execute the `insertDataQuery`?

Comment: Is there really a space here: `AUTOINCRE MENT`?